# PHP Login without database - Why approach like this won't work?

Tags: php, authentication

So I'm developping a small site, and I want it to be visible only to me and my friend as I'm only developping it, and .htaccess is not what I want now. I'm not too good with PHP, and I've managed to write this:

```
<?
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
if($user == "xxx1" or "xxx2" and $pass == "xxx1" or "xxx2"){
    setcookie("notrandom", "Success", time()+3600);
}
else{
    setcookie("notrandom", "Success", time()-3600);
}
header("Location:index.php");
```

With this positioned on the page navbar so it will kill the content of the page if user hasn't logged in and only shows the login form:

```
<?php 
if(empty($_COOKIE['notrandom'])){
    echo '
    <form class="form-inline navbar-form pull-right" method="post" action="kirjaudu.php">
  <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Käyttäjätunnus" name="user">
  <input type="password" class="input-medium" placeholder="Salasana" name="pass">

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Kirjaudu</button>
</form>
</div>
</div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
</div>
    ';
    die();
}

?>
```

However, my problem is that the script will accept **any** username and password typed, so I'm misusing `or` and `and` here?

How I should do this? How would I use this?

```
$user = array("User1"=>"Pass1", 
              "User2"=>"Pass2");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What you are doing:

When you do `($user == "xxx1" or "xxx2")`, what you are actually doing is comparing `$user` with `"xxx1"`, then, `OR'ing` that with `"xxx2"`, which yields `TRUE`.
Your condition **is incorrect.**

**[Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)**

---

#### Fix:

It should be:

```
if(($user == "xxx1" and $pass == "xxx1") or ($user == "xxx2" and $pass == "xxx2")){
...
...
}
```

This will evaluate to `TRUE` for

```
case1: username = xxx1, password = xxx1
case2: username = xxx2, password = xxx2
```

Comment: Nope.  This condition would pass with username/password xxx1/xxx2, which is not what you intended I'm sure.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen I updated the answer, it shouldn't do that now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Code:

```
<?
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];

if(($user == "xxx1" && $pass == "xxx1") || ($user == "xxx2" && $pass == "xxx2")){
     setcookie("notrandom", "Success", time()+3600);
}
else{
     setcookie("notrandom", "Success", time()-3600);
}
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Nope.  This condition would pass with username/password xxx1/xxx2, which is not what you intended I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

This statement doesn't do what you think it does:

```
if($user == "xxx1" or "xxx2" and $pass == "xxx1" or "xxx2")
```

Is really like writing:

```
if ($user=="xxx1" or ("xxx2" != false and $pass == "xxx1") or "xxx2" != false)
```

So the statement is always true, because "xxx2" is never false.

What you wanted was:

```
if ( ($user=="xxx1" and $pass=="xxx1") or ($user=="xxx2" and $pass=="xxx2") )
```

You can use an array with as many usernames/passwords as you like.  Just make sure you check to make sure the user key exists before attempting to compare its value:

```
$userArray = array("User1"=>"Pass1", "User2"=>"Pass2");

if (array_key_exists($user, $userArray) && $userArray[$user] == $pass) {
    // user is logged in!
} else {
    // user is not logged in
}
```

You still have a problem with your cookie.  Why not just use sessions:

```
session_start();
if (array_key_exists($user, $userArray) && $userArray[$user] == $pass) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
} else if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
}

// then later whenever you want to detect if the user is logged in or not...

if ($_SESSION['loggedIn']) { 
    // ... do stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,it may be faster in execution, avoiding unecessary comparison

```
<?
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];

if($user == "xxx1" && $pass == "xxx1") {
     setcookie("notrandom", "Success", time()+3600);
}
else if($user == "xxx2" && $pass == "xxx2){
setcookie("notrandom", "Success", time()+3600);
}
else{
     setcookie("notrandom", "Success", time()-3600);
}
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: This will not be faster in execution; PHP (and most languages) support [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so once enough of the expression has been evaluated to confirm a true or false result, it stops evaluating the rest.  In a language which didn't support this, your version would sometimes be faster, but it isn't in PHP.